# C99 Variable-length arrays Wikipedia example

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I came across this example of C99 Variable-length arrays on Wikipedia:

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float vals[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vals[i] = read_val();
    return process(vals, n);
}
```

Is this incorrect? I was under the impression that variable-length arrays are still just pointers which means the above code is passing the expired pointer vals to the process(...) function.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  They just *decay* to pointers -- annoyingly easily, some would say.

Comment: +1 for "Arrays are not pointers".  See also section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pointer hasn't expired. It is a pointer to valid memory until the end of the function read_and_process. Which means it is still defined when process is called.

This would be an example of invalid usage:

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float vals[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vals[i] = read_val();
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. As long as you're growing the stack the memory address must still be valid.

Comment: @Jeff: A better way to look at it: the array (or any local non-`static` object) continues to exist until the function that created it returns. (Actually it's tied to the enclosing *block*, but it's the same in this case.)  The lifetime of a local object is a span of *time* during execution, not a region of program text. Calling `process` doesn't terminate the execution of `read_and_process`, so the array still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the stack frame that contains all of `read_and_process()`'s automatic variables, including `float vals[n]`, is still valid and in memory when `process()` is executed.